# can't list taxonomies in meta box

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, meta-boxes

I am getting empty taxonomy list in taxonomy meta box. I have created several terms under my taxonomy but I can't even find one.

My code for custom post type

```
$args = array(
       'labels' => $labels, 
       'public' => true,
       'publicly_queryable' => true,
       'show_ui' => true,
       'query_var' => true,
       'rewrite' => true,
       'show_in_menu' => false,
       'hierarchical' => false,
       'menu_position' => NULL,
       'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'author', 'comments', $this->taxonomy /* 'teams' */),
       'taxonomies' => array($this->taxonomy /* 'teams' */)
     );

 register_post_type( $this->postType /* 'videos' */, $args);
```

And My taxonomy

```
   register_taxonomy($this->taxonomy /* 'teams' */, $this->postType /* 'videos' */,array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => false,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
     );
```

Comment: But, where's the meta box code?

Comment: when we add taxonomy to support argument for custom post type, wordpress automatically add taxonomy metabox for that post type at add new page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447757/taxonomy-is-not-working/19462792#19462792